# At Sails.js, how can I query a model with criteria at associations

Tags: sails.js

At Sails.js (which is using Waterline ORM), how can I query a model that return records only when the criteria is right for the associations.  Followings are the codes:

```
Order.find()
.populate('books', {title: {startsWith: 'Star Trek'}})
.exec(function (err, foundOrders) {
  ....
});
```

The models are as below:

Order:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    ...
    books: {
      collection: book,
      via: order
      through: orderbook
    }
}
```

Book:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    ....
    order: {
      collection: order,
      via: book
      through: orderbook
  }
}
```

Orderbook:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    order: {
      model: order
    },
    book: {
      model: book
    }
  }
}
```

I found that the resulting recordset is all orders.  Only that the populated result of each order contains only books which title starts with 'Star Trek'.

That's not what I want.  I want to return orders that only have books which title starts with 'Star Trek'.

Please anyone can suggest how to make right to my query statement?

Comment: to further clarify my question, the above code will get all order records.  Those order without books' title start with 'Star Trek' will have an empty books array.  What I want to get is that the code should return order with array of books that title start with 'Star Trek' only.  Order with empty book arrasy should be excluded.  How do I get that?  Right now I need to apply an array filter after getting the result.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

When you will check: http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/populate , you will find:

> Something.find()
>   .populate(association, subcriteria)
>   .exec(function afterwards(err, populatedRecords){
>   });

So you can use it e.g. like in docs:

```
User.find({
  name:'Finn'
}).populate('currentSwords', {
  where: {
    color: 'purple'
  },
  limit: 3,
  sort: 'hipness DESC'
}).exec(function (err, usersNamedFinn){
```

Nice and easy. Good luck!

Comment: No, that is not the question I'm asking.  Maybe I'm not asking clear enough.  Using your example, what you can get is for every record of user, you get a set of currentSwords which color is purple.  But you can also get those users whose don't have currentSwords which color is purple.  Only that these users' currentSwords attribute is an empty array.  What I want to get is to exclude these users in the result set.

Comment: I can't try it right now, but did you try to simply add `currentSwords` as criteria in `user.find`?

Comment: I would then suggest to put is as an issue on Github. Sails can handle lot of things which are not documented and sometimes GH issues are the only way to figure it out

Comment: if you will get the answer - please post solution here (mention me if possible to let me know) to leave it for other people's reference

Answer (score 1):

After googling for this question several days, I still couldn't find a good solution.  But I have solved the question in a less perfect way, but at least it works.

```
Book.find({title: {startsWith: 'Star Tek'}}).populate('orders')
.exec(function (err, foundBooks) {
  if (err) return res.negotiate(err);
  var orderIds = [];
  for (var i=0; i<foundBooks.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<foundBooks[i].orders.length; j++) {
      orderIds.push(foundBooks[i].orders[j].id;
    }
  }
  Order.find({id: orderIds}).populate('books').populate( .. some other associations .. )
  .exec(function (err, foundOrders) {
    ...
  });
});
```

Hope that somebody would suggest a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem trying to return users with a given role. I did a find() on my User model and populated the roles association with the criteria for a "student" role. I had the same results: all of my users were returned, but some just had an empty roles association. I solved it with an array filter.

```
let students = await User.find({})
  .populate('school')
  .populate('roles', { where: { name: 'student' }});
sails.log("Full result set:", students);
filteredStudents = students.filter( element => {
    sails.log(element.roles);
    return element.roles.length != 0;
});
console.log("Filtered result set:", filteredStudents);
```

The key piece is checking the length of the association array to see if it's non-empty. For this particular question (which I realize is now over four years old) here is what I would suggest (starting after the `....`):

```
Order.find()
.populate('books', {title: {startsWith: 'Star Trek'}})
.exec(function (err, foundOrders) {
  ....
  var filteredOrders = foundOrders.filter( element => element.books.length != 0 );
  // move on with your day using filteredOrders
});
```